# Error SOOMLA GoogleIabHelpe Can’t consume Item. No token

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, in-app-billing, soomla

I am using soomla framework with cocos2dx android
I tried with the android.test.purchase and it worked fine. 
But when i check with the real purchase item it doesnt work at all. 
And it purchased only one time but it is unmanaged item.

Heres some of the code : 
Purchase Asset:

```
 CCVirtualGood *shieldAdded = CCSingleUseVG::create(
                  __String::create("3 Shields"),
                  __String::create("Increase 3 Shields"),
                  __String::create("shields_increase"),
                  CCPurchaseWithMarket::createWithMarketItem(CCMarketItem::create(
                                __String::create(SHIELDS_PURCHASEID),
                                CCDouble::create(0.99))
                  )
        );
```

Event Handler :

This is the function that calling back i think when it succeeded :

```
if(purchasable->getItemId()->compare("shields_increase")==0)
        {
             int shieldNumber=UserDefault::getInstance()->getIntegerForKey(shieldSaverNumber, 0);
                     shieldNumber+=3;
                     UserDefault::getInstance()->setIntegerForKey(shieldSaverNumber, shieldNumber);
        }
```

Store Scene :

This the calling methods for purchase :

```
 soomla::CCSoomlaStore::getInstance()->startIabServiceInBg();
                  soomla::CCError *err;
                  soomla::CCStoreInventory::sharedStoreInventory()->buyItem("shields_increase", &err);
                  if (err != NULL) {
                      log("error %s",err->getInfo());
                  }
```

Comment: You should really ask your SOOMLA questions on http://answers.soom.la

Comment: didnt use soomla :) and it works